# How do I identify unknown film from the sequence of apparently random numbers?

Tags: film, 35mm, negative-film, equipment-identification

I should probably keep a log of what film I use... I'm currently scanning this color negative film, and finding that I not only have no idea what type of film this is, but there is also no indication on the film itself.

[image]

Just these random numbers (EJ 06 3677 9344), and somewhat unusual perf shapes... also some signs like a <kbd>*</kbd> and a <kbd>$</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Those "random" numbers are coded to indicate what type of film that is.

Comment: The numbers are not random, they were were chosen specifically by the manufacturer for identification purposes. Each  type of film from that manufacturer will have its own specific code of numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m on mobile so forgive the brevity.

How to read the code: https://www.kodak.com/uploadedfiles/motion/US_plugins_acrobat_en_motion_newsletters_filmEss_18_KeyKode.pdf

A code list: https://evertz.com/resources/FilmID.pdf

Your film: Vision3 500T

Comment: Cinestill 800T is a version of _Kodak Vision 3 5219_ with the remjet backing removed so it can be processed in C-41 chemistry. This process also increases the effective ISO from 500 to 800. It's possible that you bought Cinestill film.

Comment: Thanks Osullic - yep this is it